# Non-recursive algorithm with exponential running time

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

It is well-known, that there are many recursive algorithms running in exponential time, e.g. branching algorithm, backtracking etc. . My question is, is it possible to construct a non-recursive algorithm running in exponential time asymptotically?

Comment: Something like "take $n$ and directly sum all numbers from $1$ to $2^n$"? (and "recursive algorithm" isn't very well defined category, as any recursive algorithm can be rewritten without explicit recursion)

Comment: Any recursive program can be rewritten using while loops and stacks to get a program with the same time and space capacity, so just take a recursive program with exponential runtime and apply this rewriting procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $G$ be a finite permutation group given by a generating sequence of size $k := \log |G|$. We can list out the elements of $G$ in time $2^{k}$. No recursion is involved.